# Javascript behavior while returning name. Returns undefined instead of referenceError

Tags: javascript, undefined, referenceerror

I am trying to figure out the difference between undefined and not defined. So below is one simple program.

```
var name = 'John';
var age = 30;

var obj = {
    //name: 'Joe',
    age: 29,
    getInnerName: function() {
        return this.name;
    },
    getOuterName: () => {
        return this.name;
    }
}

console.log(obj.getInnerName()); //undefined
console.log(obj.getOuterName()); John
```

My doubt is, why first console.log writes undefined and not the error -> Uncaught ReferenceError: name is not defined?

Explanation is appreciated!

**PS** - Please correct the question If I fail to convey What I meant.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, that error : `Uncaught ReferenceError: name is not defined`
occurs when you use a variable that is not defined, example:

```
test === 'test'
VM948:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

but when you use `this.name`, it won't cause that error, because it's not a variable, it's a property of `this`, so you get `undefined` in return, or the value of that property if it exists

in your particular case, since `this === window`,
`name` and `this.name` will give the same result, but that's not always the case

However trying to use that property for example like that :

```
this.doesNotExist.toString()
VM1202:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')
    at <anonymous>:1:19
```

will cause an error

also you need to understand the differences between arrow functions and normal functions, look a this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361380/8126784

Comment: Thanks @LK7. "but when you use this.name, it won't cause that error, because it's not a variable, it's a property of this, so you get undefined in return"
This line helped me understand why it did not throw any error.